# LinkediIn API V2 - 500 intermittent error when fetching organizational entities data using projections

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to retrieve details for the companies where a user is an administrator using the request and projections bellow.

Sometimes it fails with a 500 error code and returns an unknown reason message. If I try again after a long time, it usually works.

**Sample request**

```
GET "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityAcls?q=roleAssignee&role=ADMINISTRATOR&projection=(elements*(*,organizationalTarget~(localizedName,vanityName,logoV2(original~:playableStreams),id)))"
```

**Sample response**

```
{
  "elements": [{
    "role": "ADMINISTRATOR",
    "roleAssignee": "urn:li:person:dV",
    "state": "REVOKED",
    "organizationalTarget!": {
        "message": "URN Resolution failed for unknown reasons.: com.linkedin.r2.RemoteInvocationException: GatewayException{_serviceErrorCode=null}",
        "status": 500
    },
    "organizationalTarget": "urn:li:organization:1"
  }, {
    "role": "ADMINISTRATOR",
    "roleAssignee": "urn:li:person:dV",
    "state": "APPROVED",
    "organizationalTarget!": {
        "message": "URN Resolution failed for unknown reasons.: com.linkedin.r2.RemoteInvocationException: GatewayException{_serviceErrorCode=null}",
        "status": 500
    },
    "organizationalTarget": "urn:li:organization:9"
  }]
}
```

Why is this error happening? Is there any workaround to get this information without falling into the same error?

Thanks!